# How to merge grid cell in GXT

Tags: java, gridview, gxt

I'd like to know if it's possible to merge cells in a GXT Grid like this:

[image: merged cells]

I suppose I have to override a renderer, but cannot find which one.
Can someone show me the way using GXT 3.0 ?

Comment: oh sorry, i'm gonna edit. I use GXT 3

Comment: Is your question about merge cells or edit cells, I am confused?

Comment: @Zubair It's about cell merging :) user1258245 showed me the way to edit cell

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I edit a cell in a grid in gxt 3.  In this example I am just adding a div so I can add an id for selenium testing:

```
ColumnConfig<LessonOFY, String> name = new ColumnConfig<LessonOFY, String>(lessonProperties.name(), 250, i18n.lessonName());

AbstractCell<String> c2 = getTestingLabel(GAE_ID_CONSTANTS.IDS.LESSON_GRID.toString());

name.setCell(c2);


public static AbstractCell<String> getTestingLabel(final String label) {
    AbstractCell<String> c2 = new AbstractCell<String>() {

        @Override public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

            value = "<div id=\"" + label + "\">" + value + "</div>";
            sb.appendHtmlConstant(value);
        }

    };
    return c2;
}
```

value is just the value that would have been set in the grid orignally

Now that you raised the question, I really want to do the same thing.  Let me know how it goes if you will.  Please!

Comment: Thanks ! I think I'm going to work on it tomorrow. I'll keep you in touch :)

Comment: @Nizil No rush, but yeah please do!

Comment: After a day of work... I think the architecture of Grid doesn't allow cell merging without a huge amount of code (or I don't find the right way :P). So I switch to use GroupingView [link](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:groupinggrid)

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a solution for merge cells or edit cells?

Comment: @NiziL but `GroupingView` supports only one level grouping.